# Camel Routing - replace DTO in message body with HTTP payload

Tags: java, apache-camel

For some reason - and don't ask me why -  I need to pass a simple Data Transfer Object (DTO) into my route. This DTO holds values that are required to construct a HTTP url, which is called futher down the route. I  want to replace the DTO in the message body with whatever object is returned by the call to the HTTP url (REST call that returns JSON).

I got all this working, but **am not quite happy with my solution**:

```
  from("direct:callRouteWithDtoInBody")
    .setHeader("url", simple("{{host}}/video?pageNumber=${body.pageNumber}"))
    // need to empty body, otherwise ensuing call to http component won't overwrite message payload
    .setBody(simple("null"))
    .toD("${header.url}")
```

As you can see, I am employing a little hack to get the body message  replaced: I am clearing the body beforehand. If I don't clear the body, the original message (the DTO) will not get replaced by the response of the HTTP call.

**I will award my points to he/she who can show me a more elegant** (and less hacky) **solution.**

Comment: If you append to end .log("${in.body}") and remove that setBody before, is body still that DTO?

Answer (score 0):

Several things could be happening why you require a null request payload:

1. The server doesn't like request payloads in GET requests, or is processing the request differently due to the payload being present.
2. Your DTO is not `Serializable`, therefore it cannot be sent on the wire.

With regards to **further simplification**...

Camel stores the original message in the `UnitOfWork` (UoW) by default, and you can access it via the [`getOriginalInMessage()`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/spi/UnitOfWork.html#getOriginalInMessage()).

Hence, even if you set the body to `null`, the original IN body remains accessible. So in theory you could do the following to reduce the *LoC count*:

```
from("direct:callRouteWithDtoInBody")
    .setBody(constant(null))
    .toD("{{host}}/video?pageNumber=${exchange.unitOfWork.originalInMessage.body.pageNumber}");
```

However, due to some limitations in the [`OGNL`](https://camel.apache.org/ognl.html) and bean binding logic in Camel, I haven't managed to get to a working solution. Camel is unable to deal with:

1. `getBody()` (it discards the method for being abstract) – nor –
2. `body` (it considers it to be ambiguous).

In reality, `getBody()` should work, but unfortunately [this ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9032) removed all abstract methods from consideration (I don't share this rationale) from 2.15.3 and 2.16.0 onwards.

Since you are using the `toD` DSL, I can infer that **you are on >= 2.16.0**, so I can't offer you a working solution if your priority is to reduce the *lines of code* metric. However, there are **other solutions we can consider if you want to**; just ask in the comments and I'll update the answer.

But I will get this dealt with at the community (I'm a committer and PMC).